# Equal height for the rows to occupy maximum area of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have created [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrgbJ) structure, in which I have 10 rows on the screen.

All rows have `height:10%;`

If you check in chrome you will find the height of rows is not same, there is `1px` 
difference.

I need to achieve below output

1. All the rows of **equal height**.
2. There should be **same space at top and bottom**. I can **not give fixed height** 
   to `ul` as I want to occupy maximum area of the screen.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What are the browsers you tried? only chrome alone?

Comment: Probably just a sub-pixel thing but according to dev tools all the `li` are the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery.

Here is the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/gFiAz)

jQuery

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var contentHeight = windowHeight-(windowHeight%10);
var topSpace = (windowHeight%10)/2;
$('ul').css({
  marginTop: topSpace,
  height: contentHeight
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Tushar for your reply, is this possible using only css?

Comment: I don't think so, as Paulie_D commented its a sub pixel issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting `box-sizing: border-box;` and clean your border like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uHdqt);

This way you discount border calculation for your row height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this does not solve my problem. For now I may go with the solution giving by Tushar.

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
  padding:12px;
  display:block;
  background: yellow; 
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

try this code